# A question about integration of spherical harmonics on $(S ^ 2, can)$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, integration, harmonic-functions

Question: suppose that $H_{n_1}, H_{n_2}, H_{n_3} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ are Spherical Harmonics of degrees $n_j$ $(j = 1, 2, 3)$ with $n_1 > n_2 + n_ 3$. Then, it is true that 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^2} H_{n_1} H_{n_2} H_{n_3} dS = 0  \; ? $$

Obs.: My failed attempt to solve this question  was to show that $H_{n_2} H_{n_3}$ is a sum of 
Spherical Harmonics $H_m$ of degrees at most  $m < n_1$ and to use the orthogonality property in $L^2({S}^2)$.

Comment: View these as the restriction of harmonic homogeneous polynomials. Then $H_{n_2} H_{n_3}$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n_2 + n_3$, which can be written as a linear combination of *harmonic* homogeneous polynomials of degree at most $n_2 + n_3$. Now you can apply orthogonality.

Comment: Dear @PerterHumphries,  it is not clear of my viewpoint that $H_{n_2} H_{n_3}$ is a homogeneous polynomial because $\Delta (fg) = f \Delta g + g \Delta f + \langle \nabla f, \nabla g \rangle$. Thus, the product of them is not necessarily harmonic.

Comment: as Paul Garrett clarified in his answer, I did not claim that $H_{n_2} H_{n_3}$ was harmonic, only that it was homogeneous. The key point is that homogeneous polynomials can be written as linear combinations of harmonic homogeneous polynomials when restricted to the sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Just clarifying @PeterHumphries' comment: the product $H_{n_2}H_{n_3}$ is certainly homogeneous, and by one of the set-up lemmas in an elementary treatment of spherical harmonics, can be written as a sum of terms of the form $(r^2)^k\cdot f_{n_2+n_3-2k}$ where $f_{n_2+n_3-2k}$ is a homogeneous and harmonic polynomial of degree equal to its subscript. Integrals on the sphere ignore the powers of radius, of course, so orthogonality of harmonic polynomials of different degrees still does give the result, since
$$
n_2+n_3-2k \le n_2+n_3 < n_1
$$

Comment: Paul, just a typo reporting. There is a typo in your post (should be $f_{n_2+n_3-2k}$ and not $f_{n_2+n_3= 2 k}$).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, ah, thanks, I'll fix it now.